# How long will a cube of Plutonium-238 keep my tea warm?

Tags: thermodynamics, radioactivity

Plutonium-238 gives off heat, which reduces over time due to its half-life. Suppose I have a mug of tea in a room temperature environment, and instead of dropping in a sugar cube, I dropped in a plutonium cube. How long will the mug of tea remain at a reasonable temperature?

If the cube either fails to prevent the tea cooling down, or is so hot it causes the water to boil, please adjust the size of the cube.

Comment: Since you're a gamer, the better question is "will you live long enough to drink the mug of tea?" Plutonium is extremely toxic as well as radioactive. :)

Comment: Plutonium may be enclosed in stainless steel so both toxicity and radiation (alpha only) becomes less of a problem.

Comment: I vote for reopen. This is a fun physics question, linking radiophysics to everyday thermodynamics. Pu238 produces 0.568 W/g and has a half-life of 87 years, so the relevant questions are what the heat loss from a standard cup of tea is and what reasonable tea temperatures are. Once these are known one can answer the question.

Comment: I bet this was SMBC inspired: https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/pu .

Comment: I agree it's a cool question, but still a specific-calculation, "homework" one, so I'm voting to keep it closed, according to the rules...

Comment: Ah, too bad about closing, I was struggling to work out when the heat decay of the plutonium-238 (due to its half life) would drop below the natural cooling effect of the tea. They seem to be two opposite non-linear effects and it's tricky to work out the time to reach the equilibrium point. And yes, SMBC inspired 

Answer (score 2):

Somebody on Wikipedia helpfully [did the calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-238). I will repeat some of the highlights here:

Given the half life of Pu-238 (87.7 years), the molar mass (238!), one gram of Pu-238 has a specific activity of 634 GBq.

We know the mean energy of the emitted alpha particle, and conclude that the energy generated by a gram of Pu-238 (assuming the alpha particles don’t escape which is reasonable when it’s submerged in a cup of tea) is about 0.57 W.

Now a typical cup of tea might start out with a temperature of 50 ˚C, and gets “cold” in 15 minutes - let’s say it cooled down by 20 ˚C (this is just spitballing - your actual values may change but the principle of the next bit should be sound). If you had 250 ml of tea with a heat capacity of about 4.2 J/g/K or around 1000 J/˚C for the cup, then you would need 20000 J in 15 minutes to keep the tea “at temperature”. That would require about 20 W of heat - that seems like a lot. A USB powered “cup heater” draws about 1A at 5V, so that would be 5 W.

So we are looking at somewhere between 5 and 20 W of power needed (this depends on how hot you like your tea, and the motion and relative humidity of the air: when dry air is moving over the surface, the tea will lose heat much more rapidly.

To get 5 W you would need about 10 g of Pu-238; its density is almost 20 g/cc, so you would need just half a cubic centimeter; at the high end, it would be 2 cc. The volume of a “standard sugar cube” is about 3 cc (they come in many sizes so it’s not possible to give a definitive answer - but most sugar cubes seem to be bigger than you’d need your radioactive sugar cube to be).

That suggests that a sugar-cube-sized block of pure Pu-238 would be sufficient to keep your tea hot. Of course your tea will evaporate at a reasonable rate with this much heat being added - so you still have to drink it quickly. Alternatively, if you cover the tea with a cover (even a saucer) it will keep warm by itself much better.

Comment: Thanks! One point I was stuck on is assuming no evaporation (I know, hardly realistic...) how long would it be before it drops below a given temperature (say 50 ˚C)? I assume if one cube of Pu-238 is sufficient to merely keep it hot for a while, then would two cubes keep it hot for a whole half-life?

Comment: @AshleysBrain to answer that, you have to know what the other heat loss mechanisms are. Evaporation is the most significant, and it’s nonlinear. Conduction/convection are more linear with temperature difference; if a single cube was able to maintain a 30˚C temperature difference when “fresh”, then indeed two cubes would be able to sustain that difference after a half life.